# ComboBox does not set previous item value to false

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

I have an app that lets the user type a value in a `TextBox` and then converts it from what is in the first `ComboBox` to what is in the second `ComboBox` and then displays the result in another `TextBox`.

**Example:**

1. User selects "Degree" in the first `ComboBox`.
2. User inputs a value in a `TextBox`.
3. User selects "Radian" in the second `ComboBox`.
4. Degree to Radian is converted and displayed correctly in a `TextBox` below.
5. User changes the second `ComboBox` to display "Gon".
6. The value in the (last) `TextBox` is not updated and shows the old value. **How can I fix this?**

In other words: 
**How can I reset the ComboBox so it does not remember what have been previously set?**

I've searched around for some hours, but with no luck. However, I did figure out why this is happening and how I can fix it (not a optimal fix though). It seems like it have already set the value for what is selected, and then just chooses the first one in my if else condition (see code below).

What I did to solve it was to set `DropDownOpened="ComboBox_DropDownOpened"` in the `ComboBox` XAML and in that method set all of the values in the `ComboBox` to false for each time the `ComboBox` opened. However, this is not very optimal, because I have a lot of items in the `ComboBoxes`.

I've also tried setting the `myComboBox.SelectedItem = -1` for the ComboBoxes (to reset it), but it did not work.

---

[SOLVED] Second question: While we are at it, is there any way to improve my "`performCalculation()`" method? (see code below) Because in the end it will have to check for 10 * 10 items, resulting in 100 if else statements!

**EDIT:** I went for a run, and realized that I can just use nested if loops! (I feel so dumb now).. So instead of having it to possibly going through the if statements `X * Y` times (max 100-ish times for my case for worst-case), it only does it `X + Y` times now (max `10 + 10` times for my worst-case) :)

First question still remains unanswered though!

Here is a snippet of my code:

XAML:

```
           <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxIn" DropDownOpened="ComboBoxIn_DropDownOpened"SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed" >
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="DegreeIn" Content="Degree"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="RadianIn" Content="Radian"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="GonIn" Content="Gon"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="MilIn" Content="Mil"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="MinutesIn" Content="Minutes"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="OctantIn" Content="Octant"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="QuadrantIn" Content="Quadrant"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="RevolutionIn" Content="Revolution"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="SecondsIn" Content="Seconds"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="SextantIn" Content="Sextant"/>
            </ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
private void ComboBoxIn_DropDownOpened(object sender, object e)
    {
        DegreeIn.IsSelected = false;
        RadianIn.IsSelected = false;
        GonIn.IsSelected = false;
        // Not very optimal. I have one for each item in the ComboBox(and there are two ComboBoxes)
    }

    private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, object e)
    {
        performCalculation();
    }

    private void performCalculation()
    {
        // This poor writing have been fixed. I'll leave it like this and post my new code below
        // if anyone else want to have a look at it.
        if (DegreeIn.IsSelected && RadianOut.IsSelected)
        {
            angle.DegreeToRadian(InputValueTextBox.Text);
        }
        else if (DegreeIn.IsSelected && DegreeOut.IsSelected)
        {
            angle.DegreeToDegree(InputValueTextBox.Text);
        }
        else if (DegreeIn.IsSelected && GonOut.IsSelected)
        {
            angle.DegreeToGon(InputValueTextBox.Text);
        }
        else if (RadianIn.IsSelected && DegreeOut.IsSelected)
        {
            angle.RadianToDegree(InputValueTextBox.Text);
        }
        OutputValueTextBox.Text = angle.TotalValue;
    }
```

New code for the if-statement:

```
        private void performCalculation()
    {
        if (DegreeIn.IsSelected)
        {
            if (RadianOut.IsSelected)
            {
                angle.DegreeToRadian(InputValueTextBox.Text);
            }
            else if (DegreeOut.IsSelected)
            {
                angle.DegreeToDegree(InputValueTextBox.Text);
            }
        }

        if (RadianIn.IsSelected)
        {
            if (DegreeOut.IsSelected)
            {
                angle.RadianToDegree(InputValueTextBox.Text);
            }
            else if (RadianOut.IsSelected)
            {
                angle.RadianToRadian(InputValueTextBox.Text);
        }

        OutputValueTextBox.Text = angle.TotalValue;

    }
```

And all of the angle.DegreeToRadian etc. methods just calculate what is being displayed in the OutputValueTextBox.

Example:

```
 public void DegreeToRadian(string originalAmount)
    {
        if (double.TryParse(originalAmount.Replace(',', '.'), out inValue))
        {
            outValue = inValue * (3.141592 / 180.0);
        }
        this.TotalValue = String.Format(originalAmount + " Degree = {0:0.#####} Radian", outValue);
    }
```

Thank you!